# Como interrumpir Outlook.Quit mediante VBA

Tags: vba, macros, outlook

recientemente he tenido problemas con Outlook dado que al cerrarlo no me solicita alguna confirmación, he visto que puedo aplicar una acción mediante : Private Sub Application_Quit() e intento mandar un mensaje de confirmación, pero este mensaje sale justo después de haber cerrado el outlook.exe

Hay una manera de interrumpir esta acción para no cerrar el outlook sin previamente aceptar un msgbox?